# Scrape supporters name from buymeacoffee website

Tags: web-scraping, dom

I am trying to scrape supporters names from this https://www.buymeacoffee.com/singtaousa website.

Currently, I am able to get the total number of supporters using **axios** and **cheerio** modules. The problem is I can't figure out how to get the supporters name.

I also tried to search with `span`, not a single supporters name comes out. Not sure whether my code is wrong or the names are impossible to be retrieved.

Here is my code:

```js
import cheerio from 'cheerio'
import axios from 'axios'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://www.buymeacoffee.com/singtaousa') // example
  const $ = cheerio.load(data)

  const count = $('.text-fs-16.av-medium.clr-grey.xs-text-fs-14.mg-t-8').text()
  const supporters = []

  // to be change
  $('span').each((i, element) => {
    const name = $(element).text()
    supporters.push(name)
  })

  res.status(200).json({ count, supporters })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to load all supporters with this method from console or manually because you don't have all of them loaded once:

```js
await document.getElementById("load-more-recent").click();
```

The request for loading supporters is traceable via network tab of developer tools. After loading all, you can copy a list of names from output of code below. You can change concatenation for your output, or ignore null values, but basically that's working:

```js
var supporters = $("div.supp-wrapper");
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < supporters.length; i++){ 
   list.push(supporters[i].querySelectorAll("span.av-heavy")[0].textContent.trim(" "));
}
console.log(list);
```

this script will result:

`(10) ['Amy', 'Wong', 'Someone', 'Someone', 'Someone', 'Emily', 'KWONG Wai Oi Anna', 'Simon wong', 'Elaine Liu', 'Someone']`

To get all of the supporters name you need to load all with the click script above. Otherwise you can checkout network tab to use API request.

Comment: The outputs are always undefined and then `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: I updated script to be more precise and I tested this script on Chrome console you may need to change some parts for somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The names are added by JavaScript, so you need something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or any other headless browser runner to get full-fledged script-based page content. Here is an example for your case using `puppeteer`:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://www.buymeacoffee.com/singtaousa');

  const namesMinimum = 20;
  const nameSelector = 'div.supp-wrapper span.av-heavy';
  const moreSelector = 'button#load-more-recent';

  await page.waitForSelector(moreSelector);

  while (await page.$$eval(nameSelector, names => names.length) < namesMinimum) {
    await Promise.all([
      page.click(moreSelector),
      page.waitForResponse(
        response => response.url().includes('www.buymeacoffee.com')
      ),
    ]);
  }

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const names = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('div.supp-wrapper span.av-heavy'),
      span => span.innerText,
    );
    return names;
  });
  console.log(data);
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```